# Using error function to calculate probability that a random variate falls z standard deviations to the right of the mean

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, error-function

I am imagining a normal distribution with a mean of zero and a standard deviation of S.

I know that the following function tells us the probability that a random deviate (under the assumption of normality) falls within +/- Z standard deviations from the mean:

```
 erf(z/Sqrt[2])
```

I have what is likely a dumb question: how can I calculate the probability that the random deviate falls within z standard deviations *to the right* of the mean? That is, how do I calculate the probability that the random deviate falls within - z standard deviations from the mean? Do I simply multiply the above function by 0.5?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to statistics.

Comment: As the distribution is symmetric, you could just divide the error function by 2...

Comment: @ShengtongZhang Thank you!!